# Map apk not asking for location access permission

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, android-permissions

I have a map activity and I have incorporated my code for requesting permission in accordance with the 'dangerous permissions' criteria but the code isn't effective as it's not asking for permission on my android phone (API 25).

I have used both these permissions in AndroidManifest.xml for enabling the access permission.

```
var ACCESSLOCATION=143

fun checkPermission()
{
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=23) //dangerous permission condition used
    {
        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            requestPermissions(arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), ACCESSLOCATION) 
    }
    getLocation()      
}

fun getLocation()
{
    Toast.makeText(this,"User Location access is on",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>?, grantResults: IntArray?) {
    when(requestCode)
    {
        ACCESSLOCATION->
        {
            if(grantResults!![0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                getLocation()
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this,"Access not granted to your location",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
    }
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml containing the permission:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ritika.pokemonand">
    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or 
    fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
    android:name=".MapsActivity"
    android:label="Pokemon">
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>

    </manifest>
```

I expect it to show a pop-up message requesting access to permission.

Comment: can you show me the code where you are calling checkPermission() method

Comment: @FurqanKhan just edited the question and added the code

Comment: You still haven't shown us where you call `checkPermission`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `checkPermission()`

in the `onCreate()` method of your activity

Comment: Making this small mistake did help a lot!